# Why does heat of reaction equal the change in enthalpy for chemical reactions?

Tags: thermodynamics, physical-chemistry

Chemists say something like "amount of heat consumed for a chemical reaction equals the change in enthalpy" but I cannot understand why this is the case.

Here is my argument:
Since $H = U +PV$, we have $dH  = T dS + V dP + \sum_i \mu_i dN_i$. If we assume that the heat flow is quasistatic so that we can use $dQ=TdS$, and assuming that $P$ is constant during the reaction so that $dP=0$, we have $dH = dQ + \sum_i \mu_i dN_i$.

Apparently we have an additional term $\sum_i \mu_i dN_i$, so that $dH \neq dQ$.

Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a closed system (no mass transfer into or out of system) at constant pressure, $$\Delta U=Q-P\Delta V$$This equation applies irrespective of whether a chemical reaction is occurring within the system.  So, $$\Delta H=\Delta U+P\Delta V=Q$$The heat of reaction is also defined such that T does not change between the initial and final states of the system.

Also, how can it be quasi static if there is a chemical reaction occurring, presumably at finite rate?

Comment: So Dr. Miller, are you saying that the fault in my reasoning is the assumption of quasi-staticity? 

BTW, thanks for your derivation for $\Delta H = Q$ !

Comment: I would say yes.  It takes some doing to make a reaction proceed quasisstatcly.  Google van't Hoff equilibrium box.